# Where is the rpath utility, or how do I install it?

Tags: solaris, administration

I installed an updated OpenSSL on Solaris 11.3 running on Intel hardware. OpenSSL needs its path adjusted because the gear was installed in `/usr/local`.

According to [Changing ELF Runpaths](https://blogs.oracle.com/ali/entry/changing_elf_runpaths) on the Oracle blogs, I am supposed to be able to:

```
root@solaris:/usr/local/lib# rpath /usr/local/lib:rpath libcrypto.so.1.0.0 
-bash: rpath: command not found
```

I can't seem to locate it or install it:

```
# find / -name rpath
# pkg install rpath

pkg install: The following pattern(s) did not match any allowable packages.  Try
using a different matching pattern, or refreshing publisher information:

        rpath
```

Where is the rpath utility, or how do I install it?

Answer (score 3):

The blog says it is a program which you can download and compile:

> Eventually, Solaris will ship with a standard utility for modifying runpaths. However, there is no need to wait. I have written an unofficial test program I call 'rpath' that you can [**download and build**](http://blogs.sun.com/ali/resource/rpath.tgz). To build rpath, you will need a version of Solaris Nevada newer than build 61, or a recent version of OpenSolaris.

That blog entry was dated Jun 12, 2007.  @AlanC comments that the official tool was announced later ([Nov 02, 2007](https://blogs.oracle.com/ali/entry/introducing_elfedit_a_tool_for)) on the same blog.  In that entry, the tool is named **`elfedit`**.

You may not have noticed this because the blog entry does not mention *rpath* (the wording is "Changing runpaths", likewise the [manual page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36870/elfedit-1.html) does not use that term).  The two names are related in a different blog [Land of Erik: Changing the RPATH of a binary](http://landoferik.blogspot.com/2009/06/changing-rpath-of-binary.html)  from June 2009.

Since you have posted in the CentOS topic, you might have in mind `chrpath` or [`patchelf`](http://nixos.org/patchelf.html) which would run on Linux systems.  The latter predates the Solaris blog (see [github repository](https://github.com/NixOS/patchelf)).

Further reading:

- [Shared Library Search Paths](https://www.eyrie.org/~eagle/notes/rpath.html) (Russ Albery comments that `patchelf` is newer than `chrpath`)
- [A description of RPATH $ORIGIN LD_LIBRARY_PATH and portable linux binaries](https://enchildfone.wordpress.com/2010/03/23/a-description-of-rpath-origin-ld_library_path-and-portable-linux-binaries/)  mentions `chrpath`, pointing to [http://ftp.tux.org/pub/X-Windows/ftp.hungry.com/chrpath/](https://web.archive.org/web/20141027070911/http://ftp.tux.org/pub/X-Windows/ftp.hungry.com/chrpath/)

Comment: Since that blog was written, the standard utility has been made available in Solaris 11 as well - [elfedit](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53394_01/html/E54763/elfedit-1.html) - if you don't want to have to compile anything.  It was discussed in a post a few months later on the same blog - https://blogs.oracle.com/ali/entry/introducing_elfedit_a_tool_for .

Comment: @alanc - it looks like the third blog in the series ([Avoiding LD_LIBRARY_PATH: The Options](https://blogs.oracle.com/ali/entry/avoiding_ld_library_path_the)) provides the recipes). Do you want to answer? I can provide an answer, but you really deserve it.

Comment: @jww - go ahead, I don't have time right now to write up a full answer.